# Se duplican datos que quiero agregar solo una vez a MongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Hola a todos hace varios días vengo intentando agregar categorias a Mongo, obviamente, las categorias no deben repetirse, lo que hago es recorrer con este for each todos las categorias que se encuentran en *data* pero el if no me permite evitar que se repliquen las categorias. Que puedo hacer para que esta informacion no se replique siempre y solo se suba una vez?

```
data.forEach(async (element) => {
        let categoriaActual =await CategoriasModel.findOne({
            'categoria': element.categoria
        })
        let yaExiste = categoriaActual != null
        console.log(yaExiste);
        const newCategoria = CategoriasModel({
            'categoria': element.categoria
        })
        if (yaExiste == false) {
            newCategoria.save()
        }
    })
```

Comment: Que tienes en el data?

Comment: Es un json, mira

Comment: [
  {
    nombre: 'Frasco grande',
    marca: 'N/A',
    categoria: 'Frascos',
    cantidad: 10,
    distribuidor: 'Santander',
    valor_Unitario: 2300
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Chocolatina - 1',
    marca: 'sdad',
    categoria: 'DulcesS',
    cantidad: 3,
    distribuidor: 'La placita',
    valor_Unitario: 3798
  }]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea verificar la existencia de un documento de acuerdo al valor de uno de sus campos. Sólo si el documento no existe se puede insertar un nuevo documento. sin embargo el procedimiento realizado no está dando resultado, ya que no está menjando correctamente el tema de la asincronía al momento de realizar una consulta a MongoDB usando Mongoose.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Existen varias formas de lograr el objetivo, pero lo primero es entender que una consulta a una base de datos (cualquier base de datos) desde NodeJS, siempre será un [proceso asíncrono](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/As%C3%ADncrono). Por lo tanto debemos manejar bien este concepto en nuestra aplicación para saber cómo atacar el problema.

[Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com) es un ODM para MongoDB en NodeJS. El mismo te permite crear modelos de datos, para realizar diferentes operaciones [CRUD](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/CRUD) sobre los documentos almacenados en la Base de Datos.

**Las `Queries` no son Promesas**

Dicho esto, los [métodos estáticos](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) de consulta a la base de datos de Mongoose [**no devuelven**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises) una [*Promesa*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise), como parece que esperas que lo hagan al usar [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/await).

Lo que devuelven los métodos estáticos (como `findOne()`) es un Objeto de tipo [`Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html). Y para acceder a este objeto debes usar `.then()` (como si de una Promesa se tratara, aunque no lo es), usar una función [`callback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) (como en: `CategoriasModel.findOne(filtro, callback)`, o usar el método especial [`exec()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) que **si devuelve** una Promesa.

Tu código podría verse así:

```js
data.forEach(async (element) => {
  let categoriaActual = await CategoriasModel.findOne({
    'categoria': element.categoria
  }).exec(); // <- ahora si devuelve una Promesa
  let yaExiste = categoriaActual != null
  console.log(yaExiste);
  const newCategoria = CategoriasModel({
    'categoria': element.categoria
  });
  if (yaExiste == false) {
    newCategoria.save()
  }
});
```

Ajustada esa primera parte, veamos ahora otro problema en tu código. Resulta que aunque pases una función tipo `async` al método [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) de los tipo `Array` de Javascript, dicho método no es asíncrono, es decir, no va a esperar a que todas las Promesas se resuelvan (una función `async` devuelve una Promesa). Por lo cual cualquier código que escribas después de la llamada a `forEach()` se ejecutará inmediatamente.

Esto es un problema si la llamada a la función o método desde donde lanzas dicho `forEach()` finaliza con alguna sentencia `return` o simplemente no hay más procesos en la cola. Dando paso a una incertidumbre sobre si el proceso finalizó correctamente o no. Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código se emula una condición asíncrona usando [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) de Javascript:

```js
let lista = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

const procesarLista = data => {
  let results = []
  data.forEach(async d => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      results.push(d * 2);
    }, 0);
  });
  return results;
}

let resultados = procesarLista(lista);

console.log(`resultados: ${resultados}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Para procesar listas de Promesas, lo adecuado es utilizar el método [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all), que nos devolverá una Promesa, la cual será resuelta si todas las Promesas de la lista se resuelven satisfactoriamente o será rechazada si alguna de ellas lo es.

Por ejemplo, el código anterior se podría reescribir de la siguiente forma:

```js
let lista = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

const procesarLista = data => {
  let results = data.map(async d => {
    return (d * 2);
  });
  return Promise.all(results);
}

// Ahora procesarLista devuelve una Promesa, puedo usar then y catch
procesarLista(lista)
.then(result => {
  console.log(`resultados: ${result}`);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Por último, cada vez que trabajes con Promesas usando la sentencia `await`, es correcto y necesario que encierres el código en un bloque [`try ... catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch). De esta forma, si la Promesa es rechazada, el error puede ser manejado sin problemas, evitando que el programa se cierre por causa de una excepción no controlada.

Por ejemplo, tu código podría verse así:

```js
let results = Promise.all(
  data.map( async element => {
    try {
      let categoriaActual = await CategoriasModel.findOne({
            'categoria': element.categoria
        }).exec();
      if(!categoriaActual) {
        const newCategoria = CategoriasModel({
            'categoria': element.categoria
        });
        await newCategoria.save();
        return `Elemento ${element.nombre} procesado correctamente, nueva categoría creada: ${element.categoria}`;
      }
      return `Elemento ${element.nombre} procesado correctamente.`;
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(`Error en la consulta: ${e.message}`);
      return `Error al procesar ${element.nombre}`;
    }
  });
);

// ahora results es una Promesa que contiene la lista de elementos procesados
// así como elementos que hayan sufrido algún error al no ser procesados

results.then(resultado => {
  console.log(resultado);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Espero que esto te aclare la razón del problema y te ayude a resolver el mismo.